# If the restriction of the inner product is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given a vector space $V$ and an inner product $\langle.,.\rangle$ on it, let $W$ be a subspace of $V$. I am wondering if $(W,\langle.,.\rangle|_{W\times W})$ is a normed space. In other words, whether the restriction of $\langle.,.\rangle$ on $W$ is an inner product.

Comment: Technically you need to restrict $\langle.,.\rangle |_{W\times W}$, but anyway, the answer is yes, just look at the definition of an inner product. (However, if you are dealing with Hilbert-spaces, you need a closed subspace in order for $W$ to be complete)

Comment: @mlk Thanks a bout the technical correction. I doubt that the restriction of the inner product might be degenerated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is a special case of what is called the **pullback** of an inner product.

Whenever you have an inner product $(\cdot,\cdot):W \times W \to \mathbb K$ and an *injective* linear mapping $T:V  \to W$, we can define the inner product $(\cdot,\cdot)_V:V \times V \to \mathbb K$ by $(v_1,v_2)_V:=(Tv_1,Tv_2)$.

Linearity is immediate, and nondegeneracy follows from injectivity.

Your case is the specialization $i:V \hookrightarrow W$, where $i$ is the inclusion map and $V  \subset W$.

**Edit:**

Since you mentioned you were worried about degeneracy: we have that the linear map $\|\cdot\|:W  \to \mathbb K$ given by $\|w\|:=\sqrt{(w, w)}$ is injective, and since the composition of injective functions is again injective, we see that $\|\cdot\|\circ T:V  \to \mathbb K$ is again injective, implying nondegeneracy.

Comment: Thanks. It was helpful.

Comment: No problem at all! Glad it made sense :)